# How can I walk a YAML tree with Perl's YAML::Tiny?

Tags: perl, yaml

I have a YAML document like this:

```
---
version: 1
rootdirectory:
  - subdirectory:
    - file1
    - file2
  - subdirectory2
```

that I am loading into a YAML::Tiny object like this:

```
$configuration = YAML::Tiny->read($configuration_file)
```

I see from invoking the script with the Perl debugger that what I end up with is a set of nested hashes and arrays that reflect the structure of the YAML source:

```
0  YAML::Tiny=ARRAY(0x84e3ba4)
   0  HASH(0x80627dc)
      'rootdirectory' => ARRAY(0x84e3d3c)
         0  HASH(0x84352b0)
            'subdirectory' => ARRAY(0x84e3df0)
               0  'file1'
               1  'file2'
         1  'subdirectory2'
      'version' => 1
```

So, I can do things like the following without problem:

```
print $configuration->[0]->{version}
```

and receive the expected answer of '1'. Likewise, I can also do:

```
print $configuration->[0]->{rootdirectory}->[0]->{subdirectory}->[0]
```

and receive the expected answer of 'file1'.

My problem comes from all of the a priori knowledge I need to derive my filename in the above example. As I am trying to allow the users of my script to describe an arbitrary directory structure in the YAML configuration this isn't good enough. I need to be able to "walk" the tree from 'rootdirectory'.

So, I would have imagined I could have done something like this:

```
print keys($configuration->[0])
```

which I would have expected to have returned 'rootdirectory,version' ... and so on, iterating over the arrays and hashes until I had walked the tree.

When I attempt to run the above example, I get:

```
Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not array element)
```

At this point I am stuck. As I understand it, $configuration->[0], whilst being an element of an array, is an element containing a hash that I believe I should be able to invoke the keys function against.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
print "$_\n" for keys %{ $configuration->[0] };
```

You have to force the array element "`$configuration->[0]`" into a hash ref with "`%{...}`"

So to iterate over them:

```
for my $key ( keys %{ $configuration->[0] } ){
  my $value = $configuration->[0]{$key};

  print "$key => $value\n";
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thankyou!

As I understand this I basically need some "syntactic sugar" in the form of %{$configuration->[0]} to force Perl into believing that $configuration->[0] is actually a hash and not an array element that happens to contain a hash.

Is that a fair comment?

Comment: The keyword `keys()` is defined like `keys(\%){...}` which forces you to use a hash, but doesn't auto-dereference for you.

Comment: In Perl 5.14 you won't have to dereference with `%{...}`.

Answer (score 3):

`YAML::Tiny` creates a rather complex data structure:

a reference to an array
   full of references to hashes
       full of references to arrays
           full of references to hashes
                ....

when `$a` is a reference to an array, 
you access the whole array as @$a
and the elements as `$$a[0], $$a[1],` ... 
or alternatively as `$a->[0], $a->[1]`

when `$b` is a referenc to a hash,
you access the whole hash as `%$b`
and the elements as $`$b{'somekey'}, $$b{'somekey'},`....
or alternatively as `$b->{'somekey'}, $b->{'somekey'}`

when `$configuration` is a reference to an array full of references to hashes
you access the whole array as `@$configuration`,
the first element as `$configuration->[0]`. You could just copy that to another variable

```
$firstconfig = $configuration->[0]
```

and then access the whole hash as

```
%$firstconfig
```

but if you want to do it in one go you have to write the rather tricky

```
%{ $configuration->[0] }
```

I think this is one of the things that has been removed for Perl 6.

Comment: Some of that has *changed*, but some of it still exists in Perl6.

Comment: YAML::Tiny just rebuilds the serialized data structure. The source of the complexity is the YAML document being parsed.

Comment: This helped me sooooo much. I've been reading perlreftut and perldsc and have been stuck forever with hash and array references and no real data in sight. I still don't understand completely, but at least i can work my way to enlightenment from the answer.